# Pass uint to a IntPtr argument

Tags: c#, winapi, registry

I am trying to create a registry key using the RegCreateKeyExA function. I am very new to C# so I may be wrong, but I have come to the conclusion that the first argument is an IntPtr. The problem is that I don't know how to work with the IntPtr datatype and am a bit overwhelmed with all of the different threads I have found on the subject. I need some clarification on the datatypes I should be using and how to handle them. Here is my code:

```cs
using System;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

namespace Win32Application
{
    public class Win32
    {
        public static uint KEY_CREATE_SUB_KEY = 4;
        public static uint HKEY_CURRENT_USER = 80000001;
        public static uint REG_OPTION_NON_VOLATILE = 0;

        [DllImport("Advapi32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Ansi)]
        public static extern int RegCreateKeyExA(IntPtr hKey, string lpSubKey, uint Reserved,
            string lpClass, uint dwOptions, uint samDesired, ref SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES lpSecurityAttributes,
            ref uint phkResult, ref uint lpdwDisposition);

        public struct SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES
        {
            ulong nLenght;
            IntPtr lpSecurityDescriptor;
            bool bInheritHandle;
        }

        static void Main()
        {
            uint result = 0;
            uint created_or_existing = 0;
            string subKey = "SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\Policies\\System";
            SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES secAttrs = new SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES();

            RegCreateKeyExA(ref HKEY_CURRENT_USER, subKey, 0, null, REG_OPTION_NON_VOLATILE,
                KEY_CREATE_SUB_KEY, ref secAttrs, ref result, ref created_or_existing);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `HKEY_CURRENT_USER != 80000001` for 64 bit. it signed extended. so for 64bit code `HKEY_CURRENT_USER == 0xFFFFFFFF80000001`

Comment: You may want to stick to language you know (presumably C++) rather than starting C# with interop... Have you thought to use regular managed API - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/file-system/how-to-create-a-key-in-the-registry

Comment: Oh dang I didn't know about that lol. Thanks for the help.

Comment: An IntPtr is a signed integer that is 32b in x86 and 64b in x64. Hint: use .NET's own source code for this, combined with a tool like ILSpy or DNSpy. For example this is how Microsoft defines it: https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/microsoft/win32/win32native.cs,1774

Comment: @SimonMourier Ah, thank you. I didn't know they had examples like that.

Comment: For situations when there isn't a managed library already offered (and you should check first), you can use [P/Invoke.Net](https://www.pinvoke.net/) to lookup how to define and call the Win32 API from .Net.

Comment: Why are you using `RegCreateKeyExA()` directly via PInvoke at all, instead of using .NET's own [`Registry`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.win32.registry?view=dotnet-plat-ext-3.1) class? `Registry.CurrentUser.CreateSubKey(subKey)`